# Inserting dynamic html content

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I have a form where one can add multiple questions using the "Add Question" button. If you click on the button, a new accordion-group is created.

```
<div id="accordion1" class="accordion">
      <div id="group1" class="accordion-group">
           <input type='text' id='question1' class='textbox-input'/>
      </div>
</div>
<input type"button" value="Add Question" id="addQuestion" onclick="javascript:addQuestion();"/>

<script>
 function addQuestion(){
       var previousContent = document.getElementById("accordion1").innerHTML;
       var newContent = "<div id='group2' class='accordion-group'>" +
                        "<input type='text' id='question2' class='textbox-input'/>" +
                        "</div>";
       document.getElementById("accordion1").innerHTML = previousContent + newContent;
 }
</script>
```

I also have some scripts that give styling to the textboxes, but those styles do not get applied to the new dynamic content added. And also the select boxes places inside each accordion-group gets disabled. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery by any chance?

Comment: I am not using jQuery in the **Add Question function**. jQuery is being used for other elements.

Comment: I used .append() function of jQuery and it worked. But my dropdown box remains disabled. Any help on how to apply scripts to dynamically added dropdown boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks for all the help :)

```
function addQuestion(){     
               var newContent = "<div id='group2' class='accordion-group'>" +
                                "<input type='text' id='question2' class='textbox-input'/>" +
                                "</div>";
               $("#accordion1").append(newContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/PVbRJ/

```
$("#addQuestion").live('click', addQuestion);


 function addQuestion(){
       var previousContent = $("#accordion1").html();

       var newContent = "<div id='group2' class='accordion-group'>" +
                        "<input type='text' id='question2' class='textbox-input'/>" +
                        "</div>";
       $("#accordion1").html(previousContent + newContent);
 }
```